# Sphinx installation Fails to configure with MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

When I run the ThinkingSphinx index task `bundle exec rake ts:index` I get an error. Namely, 
`unknown type 'mysql'; skipping.`

> ERROR LOG: Generating configuration to
>   ../../config/development.sphinx.conf Sphinx 2.2.4-id64-release (r4806)
>   Copyright (c) 2001-2014, Andrew Aksyonoff Copyright (c) 2008-2014,
>   Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)
>
> using config file '../../config/development.sphinx.conf'... WARNING:
>   key 'sql_query_info' was permanently removed from Sphinx
>   configuration. Refer to documentation for details. WARNING: key
>   'charset_type' was permanently removed from Sphinx configuration.
>
> Refer to documentation for details. indexing index 'video_core'...
>   ERROR: source 'video_core_0': unknown type 'mysql'; skipping. ERROR:
>   index 'video_core': failed to configure some of the sources, will not
>   index. skipping non-plain index 'video'... total 0 reads, 0.000 sec,
>   0.0 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg total 0 writes, 0.000 sec, 0.0 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg

Failed Solutions:

1. Re-install Sphinx using Homebrew on Mavericks.
   `brew install sphinx --with-mysql=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.20_1/include/mysql`
2. `brew install sphinx --with-mysql`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why it's not picking up your existing MySQL installation... but you could try compiling by hand instead, see if that works?
http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/installing_sphinx.html